# Using jQuery to filter results that don't meet a criteria (ie, have a certain class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

GOAL: to be able to turn on/off items in a list, and have items on the page with a class matching the id of the list item to become hidden. Should be stacking (ie turning of multiple items and having them all be hidden).

I have a bunch of `.projectContainer`s, that have additional classes depending on the project. For example, 1 `.projectContainer` might also have the classes `Ad` and `Book`, while another might also have classes `Book` and `Web`.

I have a group of elements that I'm using as buttons. There is a "button" for each of the potential additional classes that a `.projectContainer` might have (one for Book, one for Ad, one for Web, etc.).

Each of these buttons starts out as being selected, and when clicked becomes unselected. When unselected, I want all `.projectContainer`s with that corresponding class to be hidden (accomplished by adding the class `off` to it).

The problem I am having is that I can turn off the `.projectContainer`s using the buttons successfully, but when reselecting one button, it turns on all `.projectContainer`s corresponding to the button I just clicked, even though some should still be off because another button that also applies to them is still deselected.

AT ANY RATE: my solution is to, every time a button is clicked, create an array of all buttons that are currently deselected, then compare all `.projectContainer`s against the array to find matching classes, then turn off those respective `.projectContainer`s. But I'm not sure how to essentially run `.hasClass()` using an array.

Some code:

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
  var toHide = [];
  $(this).toggleClass('red'); //being "red" means being selected
  $(".buttons").each(function(index, e){
      if ($(this).hasClass('red') == false){
          toHide.push($(this).attr('id')); //check each button to see if it is selected (red). If not, add it's id to the array
      }
  });
});
```

So that's creating the array `toHide` successfully. But how do I run a check on all `.projectContainer`s to see if they have any classes that can be found in `toHide`?

Here's the HTML:

```
//example buttons
<span id="Ad" class="buttons red">Ad</span>
<span id="Web" class="buttons red">Web</span>
<span id="Book" class="buttons red">Book</span>

//example projectContainers
<div class="projectContainer Ad Book Web" id="p1">
<div class="projectContainer Book Web" id="p2">
<div class="projectContainer Ad" id="p3">
```

All buttons in the example are selected (red). When one is clicked, it should become unselected (red removed). It's id should then be added to an array. All `projectContainer`s with classes that correspond to items in that array should then be given the class `off`, and all other `projectContainers` should have `off` removed.

EX: say, `#Ad` is clicked. It loses the class`red`, and "Ad" is added to an array. The `projectContainer`s are then checked against the array, and `#p1` and `#p3` are given the class `off`, because they have classes that match the contents of the array.

---

### ALTERNATIVELY

It's entirely possible what I'm doing is a very backwards way of doing it, and that filtering results is much easier than it looks. I'm not a smart man. If there's  a more convenient way to do this, please let me know!

Comment: use `filter()` not `each()`!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Is it possible to pass `filter()` an array, to filter against that?

Comment: yes. I will add an example, but a sample of your HTML would be useful :)

Comment: Actually having re-read it for the 3rd time, I see that I really need to sample of your HTML to get this right :) Also an explanation of the overall aim would be helpful as I have a feeling this is an XY question and could be done a simpler way.

Comment: That helps. Q: is it an either/or, or AND relationship?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Added some sample html and a goal. It should be stacking (ie, all buttons not selected should have their respective `projectContainer`s hidden.

Comment: Is the array used for something other than keeping track of the deselected/unselected items, because it doesn't seem necessary otherwise.

Comment: Added a sample using `OR` logic. If you want `AND`, changing the `join` to have only `"."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a filter, and a constructed set of class selectors, based on the matching IDs:

This example use any selection to match:

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
    var a = $(".buttons.red").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
    var classes = a.length ? ("." + a.join(",.")) : "";
    $('.projectContainer').hide().filter(classes).show();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hdm4cyf2/1/

and this one requires all the selections to match:

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
    var a = $(".buttons.red").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
    var classes = a.length ? ("." + a.join(".")) : "";
    $('.projectContainer').hide().filter(classes).show();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hdm4cyf2/2/

As per @Artur Filipiak's answer, for AND logic, you can avoid the array by simply checking for each class in turn and enabling them if they are present.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the array to be necessary. You can hide the elements directly in your loop:

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
    $('.projectContainer').show();
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
    $(".buttons").each(function(){
        $(this).hasClass('red') || $('.projectContainer.'+this.id).hide();
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3rouwc0m/)

Comment: Yes, absolutely! This is by far the most sensible approach.